# Infinite solids similar to Gabriel's Horn

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, surfaces, volume, infinity

Do any solids of revolution exist with properties similar to Gabriel's Horn (i.e. a geometric solid with finite volume but infinite surface area)? Please restrict your answers to functions  *not* in the form
$$f(x) = \frac{c}{x^p}$$
I can already think of a great number of functions in that form which satisfy properties similar to Gabriel's Horn. Also, I'd prefer examples with monotonic functions or functions that are strictly positive in the interval $[a,\infty)$ if possible. Thanks!

Comment: You also don't want $f$ bound between such trivial choices, or you get the back door @Arthur's answer exploits.

Answer (score 2):

Take two positive numbers $s\leq t$ and let $g$ be *any* (differentiable) function such that for any $x\in [a,\infty)$, we have $sx\leq g(x)\leq tx$. Then $f(x)=\frac1{g(x)}$ will be strictly positive and its solid of revolution about the $x$-axis will have the "Gabriel's horn" property. If $g$ is monotonic, so is $f$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=-\ln |x|$$

Take it on range [-1,1].

The volume is $4\pi$, the surface is infinite.